# UI Automator error

Tags: android-uiautomator

[image]

I am new to UI Automator and trying to run script but getting error.

Comment: Please provide an explanation of what you want to do and what you did when you ran into the error. People do not want to click a link without any further explanation.

Comment: i am just clicking my setting app in phone.i am running script by creating ant build jar file.i pushed the jar file and run the command "adb shell uiautomator runtest /sdcard/UIautomator.jar -c com.android.test.Luanch".But getting above error.Is there any problem in my code writing??

Answer (score 0):

I use Android studio:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class ExampleInstrumentedTest {

protected UiDevice uiDevice;

public ExampleInstrumentedTest() {
    uiDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
   }

@Test
public void functionTest() {
    uiDevice.pressBack();
   }
}
```

In your Example to try edit:

```
uiDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)

@Test
```

And then if you  want run script i will use this command:

```
adb shell am instrument -w -r -e class com.android.test.Lunch#TestDemo com.android.test.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```